# Regex for positive lookahead on multiple comma seperated values

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to come up with a regex to extract values from DML query statements like insert, update etc for particular columns only.

Sample DML -

```
insert into abc_emp.employee (emp_name, emp_id, emp_dept)
values ('Scott Tiger', 2246, 'Accounts')

update abc_dept.department set dept_name = 'Sales', dept_head = 'Scott 
Tiger' where dept_id = 10

update abc_cust.dbo.customer set cust_name = 'Adam Jackson'
where cust_id = 1100
```

In above queries, columns of interest in my use-case are 
emp_name, emp_id from employee table,
dept_head from department table and cust_name from customer table

The regex I have come up with is-

```
(?:insert into|update)(?:\s\w+[\.]((dbo\.)?)(employee|department|customer))
(?:\s([\(]|(set\s)))(?=.*?(emp_name|emp_id|dept_head|cust_name))
```

This gives the below result -
[given regex](https://regex101.com/r/qV5PJF/3)
[image: result]

While still incomplete, I was expecting this regex to have 4 matches instead of only 3. It is not matching **emp_id**. I suspect this is due to the | operator in the 6th capturing group -

```
(emp_name|emp_id|dept_head|cust_name)
```

which is returning on the first occurrence of a match for any query. I want to have as many matches(1 or more) as possible from the capturing group not just one.
**Is there any way this can be achieved?**

PS: My final requirement is to extract the values being put into these columns and do a substitution on them for masking the data. This regex would be part of a Splunk sed script where the substitution would happen.

Regex flavor - I think Splunk uses PCRE so Perl.

PPS: I'm quite new to regex.

Edit 1: Decided to take update and insert queries separately as suggested by @CAustin

for update, i have only reached till this point
[image]

[this is the regex](https://regex101.com/r/dt9XTK/41)

(?:update\s\w+?.(employee|department|customer)\s+?((set\s+?)))(?=emp_name)|(?=emp_id)|(?=dept_head)|(?=cust_name)|(?=cust_phone)

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what your desired output is. Do you just want the values such as "Scott Tiger" and "2246"? Are you trying to somehow match the keys and values together? Either way, the insert and update commands look like they use significantly different grammar. You'd probably be better off using two separate regex patterns to process them.

Comment: The `(?=.*?(emp_name|emp_id|dept_head|cust_name))` only triggers once, and captures 1 leftmost occurrence of any one alternative in the alternation group. You can't have arbitrary number of captures in the resulting match, you always get as many as you have in the pattern. You may however use 4 optional groups at the end to make sure you can match all 4, see https://regex101.com/r/qV5PJF/4.

Comment: @CAustin Yes, i just want to extract the values like 'Scott Tiger, 2246 etc.  but only those corresponding to specific columns which are given not all. i agree that i'll have to take update and insert queries separately.

only reached till Edit 1 - for update ones.

Comment: This not a great application for regexes. If you come up with something that has an edge case failure, will you ever know it?  Consider using a real SQL parser. For example https://github.com/alculquicondor/psqlparse  https://hackernoon.com/14-open-source-sql-parsers has a list of options.

Comment: You're going to need to handle INSERT parsing and UPDATE parsing as separate tasks.